# error in loadStyle LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I use the custom calendar LWC from https://github.com/Gurenax/sfdx-lwc-fullcalendarjs

In the js controller, i get an error on loadStyle(this, FullCalendarJS + "/fullcalendar.min.css") line 30

full js controller code here... Is there another way to load the style??

```
import { LightningElement } from "lwc";
import { loadScript, loadStyle } from "lightning/platformResourceLoader";
import FullCalendarJS from "@salesforce/resourceUrl/FullCalendarJS";

/**
 * FullCalendarJs
 * @description Full Calendar JS - Lightning Web Components
 */
export default class FullCalendarJs extends LightningElement {
  fullCalendarJsInitialised = false;

  /**
   * @description Standard lifecyle method 'renderedCallback'
   *              Ensures that the page loads and renders the
   *              container before doing anything else
   */
  renderedCallback() {
    // Performs this operation only on first render
    if (this.fullCalendarJsInitialised) {
      return;
    }
    this.fullCalendarJsInitialised = true;
    // Executes all loadScript and loadStyle promises
    // and only resolves them once all promises are done
    console.log("just before promise.all");
    Promise.all([
      loadScript(this, FullCalendarJS + "/jquery.min.js"),
      loadScript(this, FullCalendarJS + "/moment.min.js"),
      loadScript(this, FullCalendarJS + "/fullcalendar.min.js"),
      loadStyle(this, FullCalendarJS + "/fullcalendar.min.css")
      //loadStyle(this, FullCalendarJS + "/fullcalendar.print.min.css")
    ])
      .then(() => {
        // Initialise the calendar configuration
        this.initialiseFullCalendarJs();
        console.log("fullCalendar initialized!!");
      })
      .catch(error => {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        console.error({
          message: "Error occured on FullCalendarJS",
          error
        });
      });
  }

  /**
   * @description Initialise the calendar configuration
   *              This is where we configure the available options for the calendar.
   *              This is also where we load the Events data.
   */
  initialiseFullCalendarJs() {
    const ele = this.template.querySelector("div.fullcalendarjs");

    // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
    $(ele).fullCalendar({
      header: {
        left: "prev,next today",
        center: "title",
        right: "month,basicWeek,basicDay"
      },
      defaultDate: "2019-01-12",
      // defaultDate: new Date(), // default day is today
      navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
      editable: true,
      eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
      events: [
        {
          title: "All Day Event",
          start: "2019-01-01"
        },
        {
          title: "Long Event",
          start: "2019-01-07",
          end: "2019-01-10"
        },
        {
          id: 999,
          title: "Repeating Event",
          start: "2019-01-09T16:00:00"
        },
        {
          id: 999,
          title: "Repeating Event",
          start: "2019-01-16T16:00:00"
        },
        {
          title: "Conference",
          start: "2019-01-11",
          end: "2019-01-13"
        },
        {
          title: "Meeting",
          start: "2019-01-12T10:30:00",
          end: "2019-01-12T12:30:00"
        },
        {
          title: "Lunch",
          start: "2019-01-12T12:00:00"
        },
        {
          title: "Meeting",
          start: "2019-01-12T14:30:00"
        },
        {
          title: "Happy Hour",
          start: "2019-01-12T17:30:00"
        },
        {
          title: "Dinner",
          start: "2019-01-12T20:00:00"
        },
        {
          title: "Birthday Party",
          start: "2019-01-13T07:00:00"
        },
        {
          title: "Click for Google",
          url: "http://google.com/",
          start: "2019-01-28"
        }
      ]
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you add the static resource to your org?

Comment: Yes i added it without any problems

Comment: What error are you getting ?

Comment: {message: "Error occured on FullCalendarJS", error: undefined} . The error is the console.log message of .catch section.. but it's because of line 30.. and i cannot understand why..

Comment: @GiorgosGalaios did you find a solution? I think I am getting the same error but only the first time the component is loaded, after refreshing the page everything is fine for some time. Same for other browsers, always the first time...